# How to: dynamic jQuery, pick at least one, validation with mask

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, validation, jquery-validate

I have a dynamic list of textboxes to capture one or more currency amounts.
I want at least one of the textboxes to have a valid currency amount.

I can't get it to quite work. I would really appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Here is what I have so far...

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/ecmascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/ecmascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script> 

  <div id="page_wrap"><form action="http://local.host.com/myform/net/send" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="myform">
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <h3>Enter an amount and click send</h3>
  <?php //foreach ($recs as $rec): ?>
  <Fieldset>
    <label for="Amount_1">Amount</label>
    <input name="Amount_1" type="text" id="Amount_1" />
  </Fieldset>
  <Fieldset>
    <label for="Amount_2">Amount</label>
    <input name="Amount_2" type="text" id="Amount_2" />
  </Fieldset>
  <Fieldset>
    <label for="Amount_3">Amount</label>
    <input name="Amount_3" type="text" id="Amount_3" />
  </Fieldset>
  <?php // endforeach; ?>

  <span class="button right"><input type="submit" value="Send" /></span>
  <br class="flt_clear" />
  </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[name^="Amount_"]').mask("$?999");    
      $.validator.addMethod("pickAtLeastOne", function(value, element, param) {
        return $('input[name^="Amount_"]').val() == "$";
      });
      $('#myform').validate();
      $('input[name^="Amount_"]').each(function() {
      $(this).rules("add", {
        pickAtLeastOne: true,
        messages: {
          pickAtLeastOne: "Please enter at least one amount"
        }
      });
    });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work. Everything was correct except my pickAtLeastOne method. Here is the working one:

```
$.validator.addMethod("pickAtLeastOne", function(value, element, param) {
  var retCode = false;
  $('input[name^="Amount_"]').each(function(value, element) {
    if ($(this).val() != '$' && $(this).val() != '') {
      retCode = true;
      return;
    }
  });
  return retCode;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check against the current element being tested, not the whole group selector, so try replacing your following code:

```
return $('input[name^="Amount_"]').val() == "$";
```

for this one:

```
return value == "$";
```

because in

Comment: Hi Nelson, Thanks for the edit. When I try that, the javascript works, but no entries, one entry, 2 entries or all entries gives an error. I want it to show the error only when there are no entries.

Comment: I see now that there are 2 issues. 1 is that initially, the textboxes are empty. the mask only appears when the textbox is clicked on. Only then the $ appears in the textbox. The 2nd issue is that the other textboxes may have dollar signs in them if the user clicked on the textbox then left the field. In this case, your solution does not work because there is more than 1 field containing the $ sign.

Answer (score 1):

just try this and instead I have use class amount on txtBox and you can modify it you want and working code [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tbgzs/)

```
$.validator.addMethod("pickAtLeastOne", function(value, element, param) {
   var retCode = false;
   var txtBoxLength = $('.amount').length;
   var ctr = 0;
   $('.amount').each(function(value, element) {
     if ($(this).val() == ''){
       ctr++;
     }
  });
 return ctr == txtBoxLength;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this Rajesh! This doesn't take into account that the mask function may add a '$' to any of the textboxes. However, I see that you are just offering another way to dod what I asked for by using a class to identify the element. Very powerful. Thanks!